# how to overwrite file_ext with same file_name on code igniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to replace/overwrite my image upload, which works. But the file have copied end up with another extension.

This is my controller

```
  function add(){ 

    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
            $id = $this->input->post('nisn', TRUE);

            $config['upload_path']          = './upload/';
            $config['allowed_types']        = 'jpg|jpeg|png';
            $config['max_size']             = 1024;
            $config['file_name']            = $id;
            $config['overwrite']            = TRUE;
            $this->load->library('upload', $

            $this->upload->do_upload('userfile');

            $upload = $this->upload->data();

            print_r($upload);
            die;
  }
```

Comment: That does not look like a controler method and it also looks like it would not compile

Comment: Please make sure you copy/paste the ACTUAL code you are running, so we dont have to spend 20 questions fixing typo's

Comment: Why would you finish a controller method with a `die;`

Comment: please paste correct codes. `$this->load->library('upload', $` is incorrect.

Comment: upload lib doesn't change the extension; although it might if the file mime is jpg and it was specified as `someimage.png` but then the image would be corrupted to begin with.